# Where do pions go in the spontaneous symmetry breaking of the linear sigma model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I have a few questions to figure out Peskin 4.3 problem which is Linear sigma model about the interactions of pions at low energy. This model consist of N scalar fields governed by the Hamiltonian ($ i = 1,2,3....,N)$
$$
H=\int d^3x (\frac{1}{2}|\partial_{\mu}\Phi^i|^2+V(\Phi^2))
$$
$$
V(\Phi^2)=\frac{1}{2}m^2(\Phi^i)^2+\frac{\lambda}{4}(\Phi^i)^4
$$
I find the min/max of the potential energy $V(\Phi^2)$, by assing negative mass
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial\Phi}=m^2\Phi+\lambda(\Phi^3)=0
$$
$$
m^2=-\mu^2
$$
$$
\Phi(-\mu^2+\lambda\Phi^2)=0
$$
$$
\Phi=\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=v
$$
It is the vacuum expectation value of the field and since it's not zero, it causes spontaneous symmetry breaking.
In part b, Peskin assign N scalar field as
$$
\Phi^i(x)=\pi^i(x) 
$$
$$
\Phi^N(x)=v+\sigma(x)
$$
v is a constant $\pi^i$pion field and $i=1,2,3...,N-1$.

Shifted potential, after some algebra, is like below then
$$
V(\Phi^2)=\mu^2\sigma^2+\frac{-\mu^4}{4\lambda}+\frac{\lambda}{4}\pi^4+\frac{\lambda}{2}\pi^2\sigma^2+\sqrt{\lambda}\mu\sigma\pi^2+\sqrt{\lambda}\mu\sigma^3+\frac{\lambda}{4}\sigma^4
$$
Here we see $\sigma$ field has a mass term. My question is, **what is this field which gain mass and why pion fields become massless suddenly**? First I assigned mass to pion fields , $-\mu$, but at the end I get massless pion fields and a field $\sigma$ with $\sqrt{2}\mu$ mass. Is it somehow about pions are the pseudo-Nambu-Goldstone bosons of spontaneously broken chiral symmetry as written [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) ?

Comment: Is there an explicit question here somewhere?

Comment: what is this field which gain mass suddenly? And my assumption at the end is it true ? I do not think it is so hard to understand that. But I will edit to be more clear

Comment: The massive field *σ* is a celebrated resonance in [QCD](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13458/what-the-heck-is-the-sigma-f0-600); in the Higgs multiplet, it corresponds to the massive Higgs particle. The massless pions are Goldstone bosons, as in the article you are quoting. This is *precisely* the SSB mechanism the text you are quoting is illustrating. If you can follow the math, you are there already.